# How to delete lines containing backslash \

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I tried to modify this: `sed '\~//~d' file`
and this: `sed '/#/d' file`.
But they don't want to work because of *unterminated address regex* error.

I could change every `\` to `#` with *tr*, but there must be a more elegant way...thanks.

Comment: `tr '\' '#' <inputfile`

Comment: `sed '\~//~d' file` would delete lines with two forward slashes and `sed '/#/d' file` lines with a `#`. Not sure how you came to those in trying to remove backslashes. Try `sed '\~\\~d'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider file foo.txt as below:

```
foo
bar
sna\fu
baz
```

Any of below commands would remove lines with `\`:

```
grep -v '\\' foo.txt
sed -ne '/\\/ d; p' foo.txt
```